# How to Subst symbolic variables in Maxima

Tags: maxima

I have a long list containing something like

```
a:[1, a, -b, -a*b, j, -j, j^2, -j^3, a*j, a*j^2, -a*j,- a*j^2, a*b*j, a*j^4, -a*b*j^7];
```

I would like to perform substitution like `j^x  ->  j^(3 mod x)`

Basically replace every occurrence in the list of the pattern `j^x (where x = 0 to 100)` with `j^(3 mod x)`.

subst and ratsubst etc seem to look for a pattern literally not symbolically.

Is there a way to do this in Maxima?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use pattern matching for this. (Pattern matching in the sense of matching expressions, not strings.) `tellsimp` and `tellsimpafter` define rules that are applied automatically; `defrule` and `defmatch` define rules that are applied explicitly. See also `matchdeclare`.

A solution via `defrule` might look like this; I haven't tried it.

```
matchdeclare (nn, lambda ([e], integerp(e) and e >= 3));
defrule (r1, j^nn, j^(mod(3, nn)));
apply1 (mylist, r1);
```

where `mylist` is the list above. (I think assigning the list to `a` is problematic, since `a` appears as a term in the products ....)

Comment: Hi Robert.  Thank you very much for your great help.  Your solution actually works exactly as expected.  However, it is totally gibberish to me, and I am a newbie to Maxima. What are lambda and [e] and what is their role here?  The maxima manual on Rules and Patterns is also incomprehensible to beginners.  Is there an online tutorial somewhere about this subject? Once again many thanks.

Comment: Hi Joe, I'm glad it works for you. The second argument `matchdeclare` is a predicate, i.e. a function which returns true/false, to test the first argument. So if the predicate is true for some expression, then `nn` is assigned that expression. `lambda([e], ...)` is an unnamed function which takes one argument, namely `e`. In all, the `matchdeclare` says to match `nn` to expressions which are literal integers (via `integerp`) greater than or equal to 3. (The test for >= 3 is needed since otherwise the result of `mod(3, nn)` would satisfy the test too and it might not stop.)

Comment: I'm sorry the documentation for the pattern matching stuff is hard to follow. You can blame me, I wrote it. I tried to be complete and precise and not too lengthy. However, that makes it hard to follow if one is not very familiar with Maxima. Tutorials on pattern matching would be very helpful, unfortunately I haven't written any. The best I can say is to search the maxima-discuss mailing list for examples of pattern matching -- searches for `matchdeclare`, `tellsimp`, `tellsimpafter`, and `defrule` should turn up some hits.

Comment: Oops! Sorry Robert, I did not mean to sound so critical.  You see, I have been using Matlab and Mathematica for 20+ years, while experimenting with Maxima only in the last two weeks. So it is like someone who lived all his life in a country where people drive on the left side of the road and suddenly finds himself in a country where they drive on the right side of the road.  Everything looks familiar, yet confusing.  However, as I learn more about Maxima the more I appreciate its power and that it can do for me everything the commercial alternatives can do. Only if I learn it better.

Comment: Likewise for Patterns and Rules.  When you suggested them, it sounded familiar to what is in Mathematica. Yet, reading the documentation sounded like a different language.  However, after reading the documentation three more times (but in reverse order, down up) it is now very clear and makes perfect sense. Now, the documentation is very clear.  Actually, with rules and patterns in Maxima I am able to achieve with one-liner what usually required 20-30 lines of code in Python or C. And I am still learning and discovering the capabilities!

Comment: If I can make a suggestion to help make documentation easier for beginners: instead of listing functions alphabetically, if you can list them functionally, in logical order.  You see, it is unfortunate that the alphabetic order (apply1, defrule, matchdeclare) is exactly the opposite order in which they are logically used.  I had to read the documentation down up (matchdeclare, then defrule, then apply1) to understand the logical flow.  or maybe, just to make this sequence clear in the introduction section. Once again, thank you very much for your help.